# How can I set the clip at the bottom right using flutter CustomClipper

Tags: flutter, flutter-clippath

I'm new with flutter and trying to make a custom chat bubble message. I saw a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964242/customizing-chat-bubbles-on-the-left-bottom-by-adding-a-nip) on how to achieve this but it's only for setting the clip at the bottom left corner.

```
 @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double factor = 10.0;

    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(factor, size.height - factor)
      ..lineTo(size.width - factor, size.height - factor)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height - factor, size.width, size.height - (factor * 2))
      ..lineTo(size.width, factor)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width - factor, 0)
      ..lineTo(factor, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, factor)
      ..close();
    
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) => false;
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5TGG.png) by using this code to set the clip at the **bottom left** corner but I do not know how I can set it to the **bottom right**. [This is what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cKYf.png)

**UPDATE:**

I have achieved what I wanted with this code:

```
double factor = 10.0;

final path = Path()
  ..lineTo(0, size.height)
  ..lineTo(0, size.height - factor)
  ..lineTo(size.width - factor, size.height - factor)
  ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height)
  ..lineTo(size.width, factor)
  ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width, 0)
  ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, 0)
  ..close();

return path;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this for the custom clipper

```
Path getClip(Size size) {
    double factor = 10.0;

    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height - factor)
      ..lineTo(size.width - factor, size.height - factor)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height - factor, size.width, size.height - (factor * 2))
      ..lineTo(size.width, factor)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width - factor, 0)
      ..lineTo(factor, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, factor)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
```

Comment: I have tried but it gave me a different result but thanks for this!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).